# Referencing in custom label enumerate environment

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I want to reference the item number of a two-level enumerate environment. The code below gives the correct item numbering, but when I reference it in the text, something goes wrong - see below the code. It should say "I prefer option 2.1" of course. Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}

    \item Hallo
    \item Hi

        \begin{enumerate}

        \item \label{item-one} Good By
        \item \label{item-two} Have a nice time

        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


I prefer option \ref{item-one}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package as it makes things like this really easy. For your example, you can produce

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}

    \item hallo
    \item hi

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*]

      \item \label{item-one} good by
      \item \label{item-two} have a nice time

    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

  I prefer option \ref{item-one}

\end{document}
```

There are many other bells and whistles provided by `enumitem` for customising `enumerate`, `itemize` and `description` environments, including defining your own variants of each of these environments. See the manual for details.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Instead of

```
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
```

do try

```
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.} % for cross-references
\makeatletter
```